# AEM 6.1 Uber Jar Maven Dependency

Tags: maven, workflow, aem, uberjar, aem-6

I am using `AEM 6.1` with `Maven` as the build manager. I have updated the .m2 local folder with the unobfuscated `UberJar` provided by Adobe. I am getting the following error:

> *ERROR* [JobHandler: /etc/workflow/instances/server0/2016-07-15/model_157685507700064:/content/myApp/testing/wf_test01]
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler Process implementation
>   not found: com.myApp.workflow.ActivatemyAppPageProcess
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowException: Process implementation
>   not found: com.myApp.workflow.ActivatemyAppPageProcess    at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.HandlerBase.executeProcess(HandlerBase.java:197)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler.process(JobHandler.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.JobConsumerManager$JobConsumerWrapper.process(JobConsumerManager.java:512)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobRunner.run(JobRunner.java:205)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The `UberJar` does not seem to have the `com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job` package. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

The `.execute` method for the process step `ActivatemyAppPageProcess`:

```
public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap args) throws WorkflowException {
    Session participantSession = null;
    Session replicationSession = null;
    // ResourceResolver resourceResolver = null;
    try {
        log.info("Inside ActivatemyAppPageProcess ");
        Session session = workflowSession.getSession();
        if (replicateAsParticipant(args)) {
            String approverId = resolveParticipantId(workItem, workflowSession);
            if (approverId != null) {
                participantSession = getParticipantSession(approverId, workflowSession);
            }
        }
        if (participantSession != null)
            replicationSession = participantSession;
        else {
            replicationSession = session;
        }

        WorkflowData data = workItem.getWorkflowData();
        String path = null;
        String type = data.getPayloadType();
        if ((type.equals("JCR_PATH")) && (data.getPayload() != null)) {
            String payloadData = (String) data.getPayload();
            if (session.itemExists(payloadData))
                path = payloadData;
            }
            else if ((data.getPayload() != null) && (type.equals("JCR_UUID"))) {
                Node node = session.getNodeByUUID((String) data.getPayload());
                path = node.getPath();
            }
            ReplicationOptions opts = null;
            String rev = (String) data.getMetaDataMap().get("resourceVersion", String.class);
            if (rev != null) {
                opts = new ReplicationOptions();
                opts.setRevision(rev);
            }
            opts = prepareOptions(opts);

            if (path != null) {
                ResourceCollection rcCollection = 
                    ResourceCollectionUtil
                        .getResourceCollection(
                            (Node) this.admin.getItem(path), 
                                (ResourceCollectionManager) this.rcManager);
                boolean isWFPackage = isWorkflowPackage(path, resolverFactory, workflowSession);
                List<String> paths = getPaths(path, rcCollection);
                for (String aPath : paths)
                    if (canReplicate(replicationSession, aPath)) {
                        if (opts != null) {
                            if (isWFPackage) {
                                setRevisionForPage(aPath, opts, data);
                            }
                            this.replicator
                                    .replicate(replicationSession, 
                                                   getReplicationType(),
                                                       aPath,
                                                           opts);
                            } else {
                                this.replicator
                                        .replicate(replicationSession, 
                                                       getReplicationType(),
                                                           aPath);
                        }
                    } else {
                        log.debug(session.getUserID() + " is not allowed to replicate " + "this page/asset " + aPath + ". Issuing request for 'replication");

                        Dictionary properties = new Hashtable();
                        properties.put("path", aPath);
                        properties.put("replicationType", getReplicationType());
                        properties.put("userId", session.getUserID());
                        Event event = new Event("com/day/cq/wcm/workflow/req/for/activation", properties);
                        this.eventAdmin.sendEvent(event);
                    }
            } else {
                log.warn("Cannot activate page or asset because path is null for this workitem: " + workItem.toString());
            }
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            throw new WorkflowException(e);
        } catch (ReplicationException e) {
            throw new WorkflowException(e);
        } finally {
            if ((participantSession != null) && (participantSession.isLive())) {
                participantSession.logout();
                participantSession = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you add the uber-jar dependency? Can you add a copy of the part of your pom?

Comment: I added the pom dependency as follows: 

 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
            <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <classifier>apis</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>

Comment: Looks correct. See my ansert below, the package is simply not accessible.

Comment: @Redman: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow - I went through the code you included and did my best to clean it up, but ran out of time (have to go to work). No griping or hard time, just a hint: you will want to _take the tabs out of your code_ when posting a question.

Comment: @Sean.. Thanks for the guideline.. will pay attention going forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reason for the error could be that your workflow process `com.myApp.workflow.ActivatemyAppPageProcess` service/component is not active because of which its not bound to JobHandler's list of available processes thus causing this exception.

Can you check in `/system/console/components` that your custom process component is active? If not then you will have to resolve the dependency which is causing the service/component to be not available.

Comment: my custom process component is in 'satisfied' state.

Comment: You mean component is active and all dependencies satisfied?

Comment: Can u share the snapshot of component info (expanded)

Comment: Component is 'satisfied' but there are reference properties do not seem to be resolved

Comment: Your process needs to be active to get invoked. Are those properties supplied via some config file? Osgi config? Is there a way u can provide those properties and then manually activating that component?

Comment: Does your component have immediate=true in @Component annotation.
If not adding that may fix your issue. A satisfied component is delayed in activation and is activated only on call, however with the implementation of Workflow you are using the Process needs to bind to JobHandler and the bind method is called only when the implementation component is activated.

Answer (score 2):

`com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job` is not exported in AEM at all. That means, you cannot use it because it is invisible to your code.

The `com.adobe.granite.workflow.core` bundle does only export `com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.event`.
If you work with the AEM workflows, you should stick to the `com.adobe.granite.workflow.api` bundle.

The following packages are exported in this bundle and therefore useable:

```
com.adobe.granite.workflow,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.collection,version=1.1.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.collection.util,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.event,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.filter,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.job,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.launcher,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.metadata,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.model,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.rule,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.serialization,version=1.0.0
com.adobe.granite.workflow.status,version=1.0.0
```

Even if the `uber.jar` has the packages , if you look on your AEM instance on `/system/console/bundles` and click on the `com.adobe.granite.workflow.core` package, you will see that in "exported packages" there is no `com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job` available. So even if your IDE, Maven and/or Jenkins can handle it, AEM will not be able to execute your code.

In AEM you can only use packages that are exported in one of the available bundles or that are included in your bundle - what would be a bad idea. You would then have two versions of the same code and that will lead to further problems.

Having seen the code I would say there's another problem here. And solving that one will help you get rid off the other one, too.

You try to start another WF (request for activation) for a path that is already used in a workflow. 
You have to terminate the current workflow instance to be able to do this.

An example for a clean way to do this would be:

```
Workflow workflow = workItem.getWorkflow();
WorkflowData wfData = workflow.getWorkflowData();
workflowSession.terminateWorkflow(workflow);
Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getNextParticipantUid())) {
    paramMap.put("nextParticipant", "admin");
}
workflowSession.startWorkflow(
    workflowSession.getModel(WORKFLOW_MODEL_PATH, wfData, paramMap);
```

Comment: The uber jar which i am using has the mentioned packages .. so using the  com.adobe.granite.workflow.api bundle does not solve the issue.

Comment: Even if the uber.jar has the packages (I never said that it doesn't have them), if you look on your AEM instance on /system/console/bundles and click on the com.adobe.granite.workflow.core package, you will see that in "exported packages" there is no com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job. So even if your IDE, Maven and/or Jenkins can handle it, AEM will not be able to execute your code.

Comment: yes, makes sense.. thanks for that direction.. but now to refactor the code to utilize the exported packages what is a suitable alternative to the JobHandler service which gives error

Comment: What exactly are you up to? The 'JobHandler' is automatically called from 'org.apache.sling.event.jobs.JobManager' if there's a job with one of the topics the 'JobHandler' registered for.  So I would think you don't have to call it manually. Can you publish a few lines of code, maybe that will help in telling you how to fix the problem.

Comment: included the execute method for the ActivatemyAppPageProcess in the question area

Comment: @OliverGebert - There have been some modifications made to the way workflows work in AEM 6.1 + to improve performance. Each process registers its-self with the process handler (it maintains lists of all workflow processes). When you trigger a workflow, internally AEM delegates this to JobManager which calls the Job handler with Workflow resource (i.e process class name). The JobHandler then goes thru its list of process to match the calling process and if found executes its. In above case, its not found and exception thrown.